# How do you write a quantum state of two particles?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, notation

Consider a two-quantum state containing one quantum of momentum $k_1$ and another of momentum $k_2$. This may be written as 
$$|k_1,k_2\rangle \propto \hat{a}^{\dagger}(k_1) \hat{a}^{\dagger}(k_2)$$

How do you write a two-quantum state of 2 quanta of momentum $k_1$?

Is it 
$$|2*k_1\rangle \propto \hat{a}^{\dagger}(2k_1)$$ or 
$$|k_1,k_1\rangle \propto \hat{a}^{\dagger}(k_1) \hat{a}^{\dagger}(k_1)?$$

Comment: Is that a state set equal to an operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that in Fock state notation you indicate the number of particles with momentum $k$.  So if you have two identical particles with the same momentum then:

$$|2_{\:k}\rangle\propto(a^\dagger(k))^2|\emptyset\rangle=a^\dagger(k)a^\dagger(k)|\emptyset\rangle$$
In general:
$$|n_{k_1},n_{k_2},n_{k_3},\cdots\rangle\propto(a^\dagger(k_1))^{n_{k_1}}(a^\dagger(k_2))^{n_{k_2}}\rangle(a^\dagger(k_3))^{n_{k_3}}\cdots|\emptyset\rangle$$
where $|\emptyset\rangle$ is the void state.

Edit: Notation consistency and conservation of kets in equations was off.

Edit2: I will keep the \propto.

Comment: Is that a state set equal to an operator?